# Switch statements for a Menu (c#)

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I am currently doing an assignment for one of my programming units and I am required to use switch statements do display a menu and collect data. I seem to have worked out the switch statement itself, but I am wondering how I return the user to the menu once a case has executed?

For example :

```
Console.writeline("Enter Customer Details (s) "); 
Console.writeline("Enter usage data (u) "); 
Console.writeline("Display usage data (d) "); 

menu = console.readline();

switch (menu) 
 case 's':
 statement 
 break;

 case 'u':
 statement 
 break; 

 case 'd':
 statement 
 break; 

 default : 
 statement
 break;
```

Now, let's say the user wants to enter the Usage data first, how do I return them to the 'menu' so they can opt to enter customer details and/or display the data.

Comment: _but I am wondering how I return the user to the menu once a case has executed?_ can you provide more detail on this matter?

Comment: Embedding it in a `while`?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw 

I am required to allow the user to enter ALL of the data, but in any order they choose. My question is: How do i return the user to the selection menu, once they have entered a piece of data. 

E.g 

User selects "u" from case statement, then they enter the required data. 
Now i need to return them to the menu to allow them to choose "S" or "D".

Comment: @ArthurRey Sorry, didnt see this comment! Appreciate the answer, the while loop works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you could embed it in a `while` loop

```
bool continue = true;

while (continue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Customer Details (s)"); 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter usage data (u)"); 
    Console.WriteLine("Display usage data (d)");
    Console.WriteLine("Exit (e)");

    string menu = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (menu)
    {
        case "s":
            //statement 
            break;

        case "u":
            //statement 
            break; 

        case "d":
            //statement 
            break; 

        case "e":
        default: 
            continue = false;
            break;
    }
}
```