# Trying to create a switch-case menu

Tags: c#, switch-statement

So I'm working on a Switch-Case menu for my program but I'm having multiple issues (I'm probably missing something real obvious here)

So first off I'm trying to implement a while loop to make it possible to return to the menu after executing any of the case methods. However when trying to implement a while loop it doesn't seem to recognise my bool variable for some reason.

Secondly I'm not quite sure how to make it so the user can return to the start menu after they've done what they want to do in the case they've chosen, this probably has a real easy solution, but I just can't find one.

[code]

```
    private string[] säten = new string[24];
    private int Antal_passagerare = 0;
    public void Run()
    {
        bool continue = true;
        while(continue)
      {
        string menu = (Console.ReadLine());
        int tal = Convert.ToInt32(menu);
        switch(tal)
        {
            case 1:
                Add_passagerare;
                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 3:

                break;
        }
      }
    }
```

[/code]

Comment: `However when trying to implement a while loop it doesn't seem to recognise my bool variable for some reason.` - what do you mean? Your loop will never end.

Comment: `Secondly I'm not quite sure how to make it so the user can return to the start menu` - I think you mean nested menu's, usually this is done by a state machine pattern... you might want to search for it, although it might be overkill for now.

Comment: Does this even compile? I don't think you're allowed to use the c# keyword `continue` as the name of a local variable.

Comment: I might be thinking completely wrong with using a while loop for it, but what I want is for the user to be able to return to the menu and use it again after they've used one of the cases. This might be linked to how I'd let the user return to the menu after using one of the case-methods, but as mentioned, that's another thing I need to find out. And yeas, "state machine pattern" sounds a bit overkill for learning Programming 1

Comment: I found the continue-while loop method from this post, might be I'm using it wrong, might be it just doesn't work in this case, I dunno. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484523/switch-statements-for-a-menu-c

Comment: Another thing I missed to add is that what I posted isn't the Main method, but rather a separate class I'm supposed to run from the main method. The program itself is supposed to be used to count passengers on a bus, placing them inside a vector by their names. For now all I'm trying to do is to start by getting the start menu working, setting it up so I can execute the methods from the menu, letting the user add a new passengers, search for a passenger by name etc. But I'm already falling on the first hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your local variable name conflicts with the C# keyword (or statement) `continue` which controls the flow of a loop (e.g. for, foreach, while, etc). Another control flow keyword is `break`.

You must rename the local variable. But because of the flow control keywords you can drop the local variable (see below). Also use `Int32.TryParse` to avoid your program from crashing, if the user inputs a non numeric value. In this context you can see the statements [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue) and [`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) at work:

```
// Start an infinite loop. Use the break statement to leave it.
while (true)
{
  string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

  // Quit if user pressed 'q' or 'Q'
  if (userInput.Equals("Q", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  {
    // Leave the infinite loop
    break;
  }

  // Check if input is valid e.g. numeric. 
  // If not show message and ask for new input
  if (!(int.TryParse(userInput, out int numericInput))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Only numbers allowed. Press 'q' to exit.");

    // Skip remaining loop and continue from the beginning (ask for input)
    continue;
  }

  switch (numericInput)
  {
    case 1:
      break;
    case 2:
      Add_passagerare();
      break;
    case 3:

      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to expand on your comment "you must rename the local variable" for others coming later: If there is a sufficient reason for readability to name a variable the same as a keyword, in C# you can prefix it with the @ symbol.  Per OP's original syntax: `bool @continue = true;`  But +1 for better flow to avoid the variable in the first place.  Infinite loops with a `break` can feel wrong at first, but are sometimes the correct way to solve things.